# Force System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", /s /t 0")

Tags: c#, system-shutdown

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", /s /t 0");
```

Is it possible to add "/f" before "/s"? Similarly to how you would add "-f" to "shutdown -t 0 -r".

In other words, how can I force a shutdown.

Comment: Have you tried it before asking?

Comment: Yes, it shutdown just as it would without adding "/f". I am not sure if it actually forces it.

Comment: I suppose if you had open programs or had something your were working on that preempts saving before closing.....and they are all closed off without your intervention, it forces it!

Comment: Can't believe I did not think of something so simple, thank you!

Comment: Most welcome. I have re-posted as an answer, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.

Open programs or anything you are working on that preempts saving before closing (like `Notepad`,`Word`, `Visual Studio`...etc ).....and they are all closed off without your intervention, it forces it!